# How to use Join in While statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to use Join in While Loop? I am trying to get total count of hosts for each year.

It is giving me 10 different tables

For example

| Hosts | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 480 | 2011 |

| Hosts | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 759 | 2012 |

I want something like this:

| Hosts | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 480 | 2011 |
| 759 | 2013 |

Query :

```
DECLARE year date='2011-01-01' 
Declare enddate date=GETDATE() 
While year<enddate 
BEGIN 
   Select COUNT(*) AS Hosts, DATEPART(yyyy,year) AS Year from table Where 
   DATEPART(yyyy,host_since)=DATEPART(yyyy,year) Set 
   @year=DATEADD(year,1,year) 
END
```

Comment: Put your attempt in the question using the [edit] feature; not in the comments. And yes, you can `JOIN` in a `WHILE`, but you'll get a separate result set for each iteration. The *real* question is why are you using a `WHILE`? SQL is a set-based language and there are *very* few times that implementing a `WHILE` is the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your query, It does not even seem like you need a While loop there, instead try this

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS HOSTS, 
    YEAR([YEAR]) AS YEAR 
    FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY YEAR([YEAR])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop, just a query with `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` will do. Something like:

```
SELECT count(*) AS hosts,
       datepart(yyyy, nmuloc) year
       FROM elbat
       WHERE nmuloc >= '2011-01-01'
             AND nmuloc < datefromparts(datepart(yyyy, getdate()) + 1, 1, 1)
       GROUP BY datepart(yyyy, nmuloc);
```

That's far less cumbersome and far more performant.